# Python LTSM webhooks into Tradingview

Tags: tradingview-api, trading

Is it possible to take my Python Tensorflow LTSM models and webhook into Tradingview to apply alerts/from my model to Tradingview charts? If so, how can this be accomplished?

I have looked at documentation and can not find the answer. I am a financial engineer so I build models and do data science. I do not have experience with pipelines etc.